# blue popup echo box at top of screen

Tags: unity, 13.04

i have this strange problem. When i connect to internet or disconnect from internet i get somekind of popup at top of screen like Connected to *router name*. And it's kinda annoying... Btw i am using unity de, tried several, like enlightenment, i3, ratpoison, but had no time for tweaking them and just used purge to delete. And still i see that strange popup bar which i don't had before... Any solution how to remove it?

edit: link, look at top of screen http://i41.tinypic.com/169mc9l.png

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that the boxes you are talking about are notifications provided by the nm-applet. It should be possible to disable them from the command line using `gconftool` e.g.

```
gconftool --set /apps/nm-applet/disable-connected-notifications --type boolean true

gconftool --set /apps/nm-applet/disable-disconnected-notifications --type boolean true
```

I don't have access to a 13.04 system but I can confirm they work 12.04 using the gnome classic desktop. You can see all the current gconf parameters and their values for nm-applet using

```
gconftool --all-entries /apps/nm-applet
```

Comment: still getting same message :/

Comment: In that case they are not what I thought - perhaps if you post a screenshot someone will be able to identify them. Sorry.